# Show that the intersection of two connected sets is connected if the two sets are disjoint.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Show that the intersection of two connected sets is connected if the two sets are disjoint. Is the set $1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9$ connected and/or compact?

I think  its compact because it's closed and limited in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Hausdorff space)

Comment: I'm pretty sure if two sets are disjoint the intersection is empty. The connectedness of the empty set depends on your definition.

Comment: Yes that's correct. the second part is whats difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is compact *and* connected.

Your justificative for compactness is ok. A rigorous person could only ask why the set is closed and limited. For connectedness, you can argue that the set is path-connected. Given two points in there, you can find a path connecting them (hint: spherical coordinates, and think geometrically).